# Print numbers 1 to 100 in 10 columns

Tags: bash

I want to print the numbers 1 to 100 numbers, but in columns: first 1 to 10 in first column, 11 to 20 in 2nd column, then 21 to 30 in 3rd column, ..., 91 to 100 in 10th column.

How can I achieve this in Bash? I have tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1; i <= 100 ; i++)) do
    echo " $i"
done
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried

Comment: i was trying below code:    #!/bin/bash
for ((i=1; i <= 100 ; i++))
do
   echo " $i"
done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bit heavy since it spawns many subprocesses .. but posting it as a 1-liner

`paste <(seq 1 10) <(seq 11 20) <(seq 21 30) <(seq 31 40) <(seq 41 50) <(seq 51 60) <(seq 61 70)  <(seq 71 80) <(seq 81 90) <(seq 91 100)`

for 1-10 in 1st column, 11-20 in 2nd column and so on..

and

`seq 1 100 | paste - - - - - - - - - -`

for 1-10 in 1st row, 11-20 in 2nd row and so on..

Note: There are 10 hypens in 2nd command and in the 1st one, <(command) means process substitution i.e substitutes the the output of the process

Edit: Approach purely using for loop

`for ((i=1;i<=10;i++)); do
    for ((j=i;j<=(i+90);j+=10)); do
        printf "%2d  " $j
    done
    echo
done`

for 1-10 in 1st column, 11-20 in 2nd column and so on..

and

`for ((i=0;i<10;i++)); do
    for ((j=1;j<=10;j++)); do
        printf "%2d  " $[$i*10+$j]
    done
    echo
done`

for 1-10 in 1st row, 11-20 in 2nd row and so on..

Comment: can we do this using loop?

Comment: @KhanduKshirsagar Why would you want to ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way!

```
$ seq 100 | pr -10t

1      11     21     31     41     51     61     71     81     91
2      12     22     32     42     52     62     72     82     92
3      13     23     33     43     53     63     73     83     93
4      14     24     34     44     54     64     74     84     94
5      15     25     35     45     55     65     75     85     95
6      16     26     36     46     56     66     76     86     96
7      17     27     37     47     57     67     77     87     97
8      18     28     38     48     58     68     78     88     98
9      19     29     39     49     59     69     79     89     99
10     20     30     40     50     60     70     80     90     100
```

Comment: Hehe yeah .. thats def easier. I just posted the 1st thing that came to my mind .. I guess I do over complicate things sometimes :P